# javascript timeout function in onSubmit login-form for RememberMe

Tags: javascript, function, cookies, timeout, onsubmit

I'm using javascript for storing cookies in my login form(Remember Me checkbox) and I would want that if user checks the box = cookies saved, and if he unchecks it = cookies deleted(that's ofc if they are saved). That should all happen when the user submits the form(login). It works when for example I put some button so when I click it, cookies are deleted.
This is my form:

```
<form name="login-form" class="login-form" action="login_exec.php" onSubmit="if(this.checker.checked) toMem(this)" method="post">
```

These are my js functions:

```
function toMem(a) {
    newCookie('theUsername', document.forms["login-form"]["username"].value);   
    newCookie('thePassword', document.forms["login-form"]["password"].value); 
}

function delMem(a) {
  eraseCookie('theUsername');  
  eraseCookie('thePassword');

   document.forms["login-form"]["username"].value = '';  
   document.forms["login-form"]["password"].value = ''; 
}
```

Ok so, I tried to make it like this:

```
<form name="login-form" class="login-form" action="login_exec.php" onSubmit="if(this.checker.checked) {toMem(this)} else setTimeout(delMem(this), 3000)" method="post">
```

It didn't work... It deleted the input before the form was submitted. So anyone got an idea?

Comment: timeout? i dont get it, solution is to catch the submit in a non-inline handler, prevent the default then delete or add cookies and then finally submit the form, your timeout will never finish because on submitting the form the whole page may reload

Comment: i already got all of that in my js code(which i didn't post cause i think it's irrelevant in here), i want it use these 2 functions when the forms is submitted, and if there's no timeout on the delMem function then the input is deleted before the form is submitted...

Comment: so why do you empty the inputs in your cookie-delete function? if i got you correctly you simply have to remove this little part

Comment: now I tried it by removing 'this' and it was the same, it deleted the input before the login was done

Comment: i made an answer out of it so its better readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function toMem(a) {
    newCookie('theUsername', document.forms["login-form"]["username"].value);   
    newCookie('thePassword', document.forms["login-form"]["password"].value); 
}

function delMem(a) {
  eraseCookie('theUsername');  
  eraseCookie('thePassword');

   //document.forms["login-form"]["username"].value = '';  i commented this out because
   //document.forms["login-form"]["password"].value = ''; you dont want to delete the values if a user unchecks remember me
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"this", inside of setTimeout refers to the window object.  Also, setTimeout expects to be passed a function, not an invocation.

better to use a listener here, but I think this should work...

onSubmit="var that = this;if(this.checker.checked) {toMem(this)} else setTimeout(function(){delMem(that)}, 3000)"

Comment: how could i implement that into onSubmit="" ?

Comment: i've posted that same code in my question, and i even retryed it now, it deleted the input before the login action